# ConstraintLayout edge cuttoff

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I am having ConstraintLayout unit inflated to LinearLayout with horizontal orientation so that 4 units fits in one line. I got layout working but its cutoff and the left edge since i use margin on right to get this margin as on image. One item is designed to as following img:

[image]

And the layout i designed for this item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageview_listunit_button"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/imageview_listunit_button"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/back_one">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageview_listunit_image"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/placeholder"
            android:padding="6dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview_listunit_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textColor="@color/color_text"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:paddingStart="6dp"
            android:paddingEnd="6dp"
            android:paddingBottom="12dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/imageview_listunit_image"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/imageview_listunit_image"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/imageview_listunit_image"/>

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageview_listunit_button"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:src="@drawable/button"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I believe the problem is with margin and i margin the black layout from red a bit, and it cuts off on left edge than. I tried with padding but no success any tips how should i solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Since the red `ImageView` in the top right corner has fixed dimensions, it allows for some margin manipulation. We set the width of the black `ImageView` to match constraints of the parent but set a margin on the right and on the top of `20dp` (half of the red `ImageView`). We then position the center of the red `ImageView` in the top right corner of the black one and there is enough space because of the margins:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/background"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/back_one"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageview_listunit_image"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/placeholder"
        android:padding="6dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview_listunit_title"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textColor="@color/color_text"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:paddingStart="6dp"
        android:paddingEnd="6dp"
        android:paddingBottom="12dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/imageview_listunit_image"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/imageview_listunit_image"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/imageview_listunit_image" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageview_listunit_button"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/background"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/background"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/background"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/background"
        android:src="@drawable/button"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: This seem okay, but there is missing the android:background="@drawable/back_one" in my nested constraint which is 9 patch bg (kind of a black border as on example image)

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: Hmmm almost what if i want that this upper image is wrap content? I am now having some weird problems with right margin to other plate when they are in line.

Comment: I don't know how to do it with upper `ImageView` having `wrap_content`. What you can do is replace the `LinearLayout` with `ConstraintLayout` for lining them in a row and experiment with chain styles if you are having problems with margins.

Answer (score 0):

Okay i solved this the other way around, i just put the small red circle on top and than margined the main layout for the half width of red button.